# findViewById method error occured

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm developing a GridView activity in a my small project. But I get an error when I try to make a reference to the xml element which is a GridView. I get 
an error when I try to use `findViewById` method. Here is my java and xml code.

java file

```
package com.example.anu.gridviewcontry;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.GridLayout;
    import android.widget.GridView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Steps :-
        /*
            01) Prepare data source [images in drawble and names in string.xml]
            02) Creat a GridView in xml (main layout file)
            03) Bring GridView from xml to java (to fill values)
            04)
         */

        GridView myGridView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myGridView = (GridView) findViewByID (R.id.gridView);
        }
    }
```

xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.anu.gridviewcontry.MainActivity">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:columnWidth="120dp">
        </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: oh i miss a letter. thank you

Comment: findViewByID(R.id.gridView); should be: findViewById(R.id.gridView);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
GridView myGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
myGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.